# Python 'logging' module error: The log statements do not get appended in a sequential manner for multiple modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am coding a project which has multiple modules for a legacy software in Python 2.7. I am logging the statements in a file called debg.log from all the modules. The code is ran from the main python file called "Automation.py" which then calls multiple modules one of which is suppose called "builds.py". I want the log statements to be printed onto the debg.log file such that it is sequential the same way as the statements are executed in the python modules.
For e.g: Let's say in the actual code Automation.py is ran first and it prints out this first: "This is the main file." and "It calls the other modules". Then it calls the other module "builds.py" which prints out "I am called by the first file". And then the sequence of commands goes back to the main file "Automation.py" and it prints out "Program has ended."
In my program the when I use logger the sequence is being printed like this in debg.log:
prints out "Program has ended." So basically the print in the 2nd module is not printed.
Now, I have to make sure such that the output printed in debg.log is new each time the program is executed so I have to use mode='w' as the logs should not be appended to previous logs. That is where the problem lies as if I put mode='w' in the module 'builds.py' it truncates the logs from the 'Automation.py' first and then when the commands goes back to the 'Automation.py' it truncates the logs from the 'builds.py'. Please help explain how I should organize the filemode such that everything is printed in the sequential manner and that it does not get truncated.
Below is the logger part of the code of the main module

```
//Small snippet of logger code in Automation.py
#import logger

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debg.log', mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

This is the logger part of the second module

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debg.log', mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

As, I said I have used multiple different scenarios by changing the mode of the file so that it prints on the log file correctly but it did not work. The only time it did print out in a sequential manner was when the mode was not included as so it went to default which is append. But then the logs just kept appending to the debg.log which is not what I want.

Comment: Just making sure - your code runs in parallel? Each module in a thread? Or are they all in one thread?

Comment: @SpiderPig1297 The code does not run in parallel from different modules. So Automation.py calls builds.py and stops executing. builds.py finishes running and then the Automation.py resumes running from the point it called builds.py.

Comment: So if your module runs synchronously, how can it's output not be sequential?

Comment: @SpiderPig1297 The output is sequential as I have seen from the print statements. But the logs are not printed onto the file debg.log in the same sequential manner. It is because once it goes onto the second module the mode='w' which means it truncates whatever was printed before in debg.log and it starts printing logs from the top again. And whenever control goes back to Automation.py it truncates the logs from builds.py again and prints its own log

Comment: So instead of opening it in write mode ('w'), open it in append mode ('a') and your output won't be truncated

Comment: @SpiderPig1297 But I have to write mode='w' since I want the logs for each time I run the program to be present in debg.log. If I do not write mode='w' the logs are just going to get appended to the previous logs from the past times I executed the program. I only want the logs from the current execution

Comment: You can always truncate the file manually before initializing the `logging` directory, and then use it in append mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222501/discussion-between-spiderpig1297-and-ashish101).